# select multiple columns using distinct in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

This is model.php

```
function get_data_wheree($table)
{
    $this->db->select('course_offrd_name','collg_id');
    $this->db->distinct('');

    return $this->db->get('tbl_course_offered')->result();
}
```

Here I want to use multiple columns course_offrd_name and collg_id using one columns as DISTINCT keywords and second as normal select. but I'm only able to select course_offrd_name and not able to print collg_id. how to print both the columns with one distinct and one normal select.
    course_offrd_name as DISTINCT and collg_id as normal select 
    I have made the query simple.
How do I solve the issue in the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use the distinct like this :

```
function get_data_wheree($table)
{
    $this->db->distinct('course_offrd_name');
    $this->db->select('collg_id');

    return $this->db->get('tbl_course_offered')->result();
}
```

Or you can also use a `GROUP BY` :

```
function get_data_wheree($table)
{
    $this->db->select('course_offrd_name, collg_id');
    $this->db->group_by('course_offrd_name');

    return $this->db->get('tbl_course_offered')->result();
}
```